# Adding a custom bit of text to PHP Twitter code

Tags: php, text, twitter, wordpress

I am using the code below, which is bulked in with the "Keyring Social Importer" plugin for Wordpress, to import my Tweets on a regular basis as individual blog posts in my Wordpress blog.

I would like to add a line of text within each created blog post, after the tweet, that says "Follow me on Twitter" with a link to my Twitter page. How could I achieve this?

So, currently my posts look like this... Title Of Post = Tweet with 15 word limit and "..." after it. Content = Tweet in full. After the Tweet in full within the content, I want this follow link.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

HT

```
<?php

function Keyring_Twitter_Importer() {

class Keyring_Twitter_Importer extends Keyring_Importer_Base {
    const SLUG              = 'twitter';    // e.g. 'twitter' (should match a service in Keyring)
    const LABEL             = 'Twitter';    // e.g. 'Twitter'
    const KEYRING_SERVICE   = 'Keyring_Service_Twitter';    // Full class name of the Keyring_Service this importer requires
    const REQUESTS_PER_LOAD = 3;     // How many remote requests should be made before reloading the page?

    var $auto_import = false;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        add_action( 'keyring_importer_twitter_custom_options', array( $this, 'custom_options' ) );
    }

    function custom_options() {
        ?><tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                <label for="include_rts"><?php _e( 'Import retweets', 'keyring' ); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="include_rts" id="include_rts"<?php echo checked( $this->get_option( 'include_rts', true ) ); ?> />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                <label for="include_replies"><?php _e( 'Import @replies', 'keyring' ); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="include_replies" id="include_replies"<?php echo checked( $this->get_option( 'include_replies', true ) ); ?> />
            </td>
        </tr><?php
    }

    function handle_request_options() {
        // Validate options and store them so they can be used in auto-imports
        if ( empty( $_POST['category'] ) || !ctype_digit( $_POST['category'] ) )
            $this->error( __( "Make sure you select a valid category to import your checkins into." ) );

        if ( empty( $_POST['author'] ) || !ctype_digit( $_POST['author'] ) )
            $this->error( __( "You must select an author to assign to all checkins." ) );

        if ( isset( $_POST['auto_import'] ) )
            $_POST['auto_import'] = true;
        else
            $_POST['auto_import'] = false;

        if ( isset( $_POST['include_rts'] ) )
            $_POST['include_rts'] = true;
        else
            $_POST['include_rts'] = false;

        if ( isset( $_POST['include_replies'] ) )
            $_POST['include_replies'] = true;
        else
            $_POST['include_replies'] = false;

        // If there were errors, output them, otherwise store options and start importing
        if ( count( $this->errors ) ) {
            $this->step = 'greet';
        } else {
            $this->set_option( array(
                'category'        => (int) $_POST['category'],
                'tags'            => explode( ',', $_POST['tags'] ),
                'author'          => (int) $_POST['author'],
                'include_replies' => (bool) $_POST['include_replies'],
                'include_rts'     => (bool) $_POST['include_rts'],
                'auto_import'     => (bool) $_POST['auto_import'],
                'user_id'         => $this->service->get_token()->get_meta( 'user_id' ),
            ) );

            $this->step = 'import';
        }
    }

    function build_request_url() {
        // Base request URL
        $url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?";
        $params = array(
            'user_id' => $this->get_option( 'user_id' ),
            'trim_user' => 'true',
            'count' => 75, // More than this and Twitter seems to get flaky
            'include_entities' => 'true',
        );
        if ( false == $this->get_option( 'include_replies' ) )
            $params['exclude_replies'] = 'true';
        if ( true == $this->get_option( 'include_rts' ) )
            $params['include_rts'] = 'true';
        $url = $url . http_build_query( $params );


        if ( $this->auto_import ) {
            // Locate our most recently imported Tweet, and get ones since then
            $latest = get_posts( array(
                'numberposts' => 1,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'meta_key'    => 'keyring_service', // In case there are other asides
                'meta_value'  => 'twitter',
                'tax_query' => array( array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'post-format-standard' ), // Tweets stored as asides
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ) ),
            ) );

            // If we have already imported some, then start since the most recent
            if ( $latest ) {
                $max = get_post_meta( $latest[0]->ID, 'twitter_id', true );
                $url = add_query_arg( 'since_id', $max, $url );
            }
        } else {
            // Handle page offsets (only for non-auto-import requests)
            $url = add_query_arg( 'page', $this->get_option( 'page', 0 ), $url );
        }

        return $url;
    }

    function extract_posts_from_data( $raw ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $importdata = $raw;

        if ( null === $importdata ) {
            $this->finished = true;
            return new Keyring_Error( 'keyring-twitter-importer-failed-download', __( 'Failed to download your tweets from Twitter. Please wait a few minutes and try again.', 'keyring' ) );
        }

        // Check for API overage/errors
        if ( !empty( $importdata->error ) ) {
            $this->finished = true;
            return new Keyring_Error( 'keyring-twitter-importer-throttled', __( 'You have made too many requests to Twitter and have been temporarily blocked. Please try again in 1 hour (duplicate tweets will be skipped).', 'keyring' ) );
        }

        // Make sure we have some tweets to parse
        if ( !is_array( $importdata ) || !count( $importdata ) ) {
            $this->finished = true;
            return;
        }

        // Get the total number of tweets we're importing
        if ( !empty( $importdata[0]->user->statuses_count ) )
            $this->set_option( 'total', $importdata[0]->user->statuses_count );

        // Parse/convert everything to WP post structs
        foreach ( $importdata as $post ) {
            // Double-check for @replies, which shouldn't be included at all if we chose to skip them
            if ( true == $this->get_option( 'exclude_replies' ) && null != $post->in_reply_to_screen_name )
                continue;

            // Post title can be empty for Asides, but it makes them easier to manage if they have *something*
            $title_words = explode( ' ', strip_tags( $post->text ) );
            $post_title  = implode( ' ', array_slice( $title_words, 0, 15 ) );
// Use the first 15 words
            if ( count( $title_words ) > 15 )
                $post_title .= '&hellip;'; 


            // Parse/adjust dates
            $post_date_gmt = strtotime( $post->created_at );
            $post_date_gmt = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_date_gmt );
            $post_date     = get_date_from_gmt( $post_date_gmt );

            // Apply selected category
            $post_category = array( $this->get_option( 'category' ) );

            // Clean up content a bit
            $post_content = $post->text;
            $post_content = $wpdb->escape( html_entity_decode( trim( $post_content ) ) );

            // Handle entities supplied by Twitter
            if ( count( $post->entities->urls ) ) {
                foreach ( $post->entities->urls as $url ) {
                    $post_content = str_replace( $url->url, $url->expanded_url, $post_content );
                }
            }

            // Any hashtags used in a tweet will be applied to the Post as tags in WP
            $tags = $this->get_option( 'tags' );
            if ( preg_match_all( '/(^|[(\[\s])#(\w+)/', $post_content, $tag ) )
                $tags = array_merge( $tags, $tag[2] );

            // Add HTML links to URLs, usernames and hashtags
            $post_content = make_clickable( esc_html( $post_content ) );

            // Include geo Data (if provided by Twitter)
            if ( !empty( $post->geo ) && 'point' == strtolower( $post->geo->type ) )
                $geo = array(
                    'lat' => $post->geo->coordinates[0],
                    'long' => $post->geo->coordinates[1]
                );
            else
                $geo = array();

            // Get a GUID from Twitter, plus other important IDs to store in postmeta later
            $user = $this->service->get_token()->get_meta( 'username' );
            $twitter_id              = $post->id_str;
            $twitter_permalink       = "https://twitter.com/{$user}/status/{$twitter_id}";
            $in_reply_to_user_id     = $post->in_reply_to_user_id;
            $in_reply_to_screen_name = $post->in_reply_to_screen_name;
            $in_reply_to_status_id   = $post->in_reply_to_status_id;
            $post_author             = $this->get_option( 'author' );
            $post_status             = 'publish';
            $twitter_raw             = $post;

            // Build the post array, and hang onto it along with the others
            $this->posts[] = compact(
                'post_author',
                'post_date',
                'post_date_gmt',
                'post_content',
                'post_title',
                'post_status',
                'post_category',
                'tags',
                'twitter_id',
                'twitter_permalink',
                'geo',
                'in_reply_to_user_id',
                'in_reply_to_screen_name',
                'in_reply_to_status_id',
                'twitter_raw'
            );
        }
    }

    function insert_posts() {
        global $wpdb;
        $imported = 0;
        $skipped  = 0;
        foreach ( $this->posts as $post ) {
            extract( $post );
            if (
                $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'twitter_id' AND meta_value = %s", $twitter_id ) )
            ||
                $post_id = post_exists( $post_title, $post_content, $post_date )
            ) {
                // Looks like a duplicate
                $skipped++;
            } else {
                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

                if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) )
                    return $post_id;

                if ( !$post_id )
                    continue;


                // Track which Keyring service was used
                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'keyring_service', $this->service->get_name() );

                // Store the twitter id, reply ids etc
                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_id', $twitter_id );
                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_permalink', $twitter_permalink );
                if ( !empty( $in_reply_to_user_id ) )
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_in_reply_to_user_id', $in_reply_to_user_id );
                if ( !empty( $in_reply_to_screen_name ) )
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_in_reply_to_screen_name', $in_reply_to_screen_name );
                if ( !empty( $in_reply_to_status_id ) )
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'twitter_in_reply_to_status_id', $in_reply_to_status_id );

                // Update Category and Tags
                wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, $post_category );
                if ( count( $tags ) )
                    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, implode( ',', $tags ) );

                // Store geodata if it's available
                if ( !empty( $geo ) ) {
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'geo_latitude', $geo['lat'] );
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'geo_longitude', $geo['long'] );
                    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'geo_public', 1 );
                }

                add_post_meta( $post_id, 'raw_import_data', json_encode( $twitter_raw ) );

                $imported++;
            }
        }
        $this->posts = array();

        // Return, so that the handler can output info (or update DB, or whatever)
        return array( 'imported' => $imported, 'skipped' => $skipped );
    }
}

} // end function Keyring_Twitter_Importer


add_action( 'init', function() {
    Keyring_Twitter_Importer(); // Load the class code from above
    keyring_register_importer(
        'twitter',
        'Keyring_Twitter_Importer',
        plugin_basename( __FILE__ ),
        __( 'Import all of your tweets from Twitter as Posts (marked as "asides") in WordPress.', 'keyring' )
    );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

This May Work For You.

AFTER:

```
Keyring_Twitter_Importer(); // Load the class code from above
```

TRY THIS:

```
Keyring_Twitter_Importer(); // Load the class code from above
print "<BR><a href=\"http://Twitter-link.com/you\">Follow me on Twitter</a><BR>";
```